# Python Pandas - Add a new column with value based on first and last name in multiple columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Although I'm still a beginner myself, I'm trying to explain some Pandas fundamentals to colleagues who usually manipulate CSV files with Excel.

I hit a wall with my ability to find a "good" answer for solving a given problem I'd like to use as an example.

I have a CSV file like this:

```
"Id","First","Last"
"109","Karl","Evans"
"113","Louise","Hudson"
"106","Catherine","Johnson"
```

and I'm importing it into Python like this:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('C:\\example.csv')
```

I want to add a new column to `df` called "StartsWithJOrK".

It should say "Yay!" for anyone whose lowercased-first-name OR whose lowercased-last-name starts with a "j" or a "k".  It should say "BooHiss" for anyone for whom neither lowercased-name starts with a "j" or a "k".

*(It's a rather overwrought example, but I feel like it packs in a lot of things I either don't know how to do or don't know how combine "pythonically.")*

**What's the most pythonic, fewest-lines-of-code way to do this?**

Answer (score 2):

Not the easiest introduction to Pandas...

```
df['StartsWithJorK'] = 'BooHiss'
starting_letters = ['j', 'k']
df.loc[(df.First.str[0].str.lower().isin(starting_letters)) | 
        df.Last.str[0].str.lower().isin(starting_letters), 'StartsWithJorK'] = 'Yay!'

>>> df
     Id       First     Last StartsWithJorK
0   109        Karl    Evans           Yay!
1   113      Louise   Hudson        BooHiss
2   106   Catherine  Johnson           Yay!
```

`df.First.str[0]` finds the first character of the name.

`.str.lower()` converts this series of letters to lower case.

`.isin(starting_letters)` checks if each lower case letter is in our list of starting letters, i.e. 'j' and 'k'.

`.loc` is for [label and boolean based indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) where the column `StartsWithJorK` is set to `Yay!` for each matching condition.

Comment: Thanks.  I made it "not so easy" so I could strip it apart into a few building blocks to understand.  Followup question, if you don't mind.  Let's say it was "Joe Evans," not "Karl Evans," and I just wanted to do a "StartsWithJ" column.  (Still "first or last".)  Would the most pythonic/concise way to do that operation be to have a 3rd line like `df.loc[(df.First.str.lower().str.startswith('j')) | df.Last.str.lower().str.startswith('j'), 'StartsWithJ'] = 'Yay'`, or is there an even simpler approach?  I've noticed Pandas solutions often change **entirely** when the question gets simpler.

Comment: Looks good to me, but someone will probably find a simpler way.  You could also do `df.First.str[0].str.lower() == 'k'`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind importing `numpy` too, you can do

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mask = df['Last'].str.match('[JjKk]') | df['First'].str.match('[JjKk]')
df['StartsWithJOrK'] = np.where(mask, 'Yay!', 'BooHiss')
```

Output:

```
    Id      First     Last StartsWithJOrK
0  109       Karl    Evans           Yay!
1  113     Louise   Hudson        BooHiss
2  106  Catherine  Johnson           Yay!
```

There are other ways of creating the above `mask`. Here is one:

```
mask = (df[['First', 'Last']]
            .apply(lambda x: x.str.match('[JjKk]'), axis=1)
            .any(axis=1))
```

Or, taking a cue from @Alexander's answer's use of `.str.lower()`:

```
mask = (df[['First', 'Last']]
            .apply(lambda x: x.str.lower().str.match('[jk]'), axis=1)
            .any(axis=1))
```

Comment: shouldn't we use .startswith in this case?Or .str.match('^[JjKk]')? I understand .str.match in your example will fire for letter in any position?

Comment: `Series.str.startwith` does not accept regexes, so you would need to check each of `j`, `J`, `k` and `K`. `Series.str.match` only matches at the beginning of the string --- just as `re.match` does.

Comment: I agree, but regexp should be .str.match('^[JjKk]') so that we match only the starting letter

Comment: `Series.str.match` **only** matches at the beginning of the string.